# Business process flow dynamic update via javascript broken after rollup 1

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm doing an update of the business process flow via javascript, based on an option set value.

I'm setting the processId and the stageId, then i force a form save, and on the callback i was refreshing the form. After rollup 1 has been applied the scripts on the page are breaking on page refresh. 
Does anyone have experience the same problem is something that came out with turboforms for some reason?

This is the code that i'm using at the moment, it works, but onLoad the script i previously set are all failing. They work on the normal load of the page.

**NOTE:** I'm aware of turbo forms and the asynchronous load of Javascript. But in this case i have a single file, and on refresh it should be cached.

```js
Xrm.Page.data.save().then
            (
                function () {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                },
                function () {

                }    
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

[Xrm.Page.data.process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn817878.aspx) has been introduced to manipulate BPFs.

- Use **getActiveProcess** to retrieve information about the active process and **setActiveProcess** to set a different process as the active process.
- Use **getActiveStage** to retrieve information about the active stage and **setActiveStage** to set a completed stage as the active stage.
  *With Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online 2015 Update 1 you can use **setActiveStage** to a stage in a different entity*
- Use **moveNext** to move to the next stage and **movePrevious** to move to the previous stage.
  *With Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online 2015 Update 1 you can use **movePrevious** to a previous stage in a different entity*

The functions should handle the visualizazion of the process flow. You *might* need to invoke `Xrm.Page.data.refresh` if you also need to change/save/reload the form contents.

Comment: Hi Alex,I was aware of those scripts from the release but i didn't use them since what i had in place was working fine and it's still doing it's work until the page re-loads. My question is about the fact that a form re-load is breaking the scripts.